# PHP construct not echoing variables

Tags: php, echo, construct

I'm new to PHP so still getting grips of how constructs work and I'd appreciate some help!

The following code is failing to echo the variables $arrivalTime and $hourStay:

```
class Variable {

public $arrivalTime;
public $hourStay;   

public function __construct() {
    $this->arrivalTime = $_POST['arrivalTime'];
    $this->hourStay = $_POST['hourStay'];

    echo $this->arrivalTime;
    echo $this->hourStay;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you instantiating the class?

Comment: `new Variable();`...

Comment: You have to make and instance of your class.

Comment: Do you have actual values in the post ?

Comment: I'm an idiot for that. Thank you!

As far as the method I'm using to pass the POST's, does it seem the correct way to do so?

Comment: Check that $_POST values are defined with something like;
`$this->arrivalTime = isset($_POST['arrivalTime'])? $_POST['arrivalTime'] : "No arrival time available";`

Comment: I couldn't tell without seeing the bigger picture... You can pass them like that or, in my oppinion better, as input in the constructor if you don't want the class to be dependent to post values.

Comment: Does this work? http://pastie.org/pastes/10516156/text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate the class, by calling `new Variable()` somewhere in your code. However, in general it is better to not have your class depend on the post variables, but pass them in through the constructor:

```
class Variable {

  public $arrivalTime;
  public $hourStay;   

  public function __construct($arrivalTime, $hourStay) {
      // TODO: Check if the values are valid, e.g.
      // $arrivalTime is a time in the future 
      // and $hourStay is an integer value > 0.
      $this->arrivalTime = $arrivalTime;
      $this->hourStay = $hourStay;
  }

  public function print() {
      echo $this->arrivalTime;
      echo $this->hourStay;
  }
}

$var = new Variable($_POST['arrivalTime'], $_POST['hourStay']);
$var->print();
```

Also note how I took the generation of output away from the constructor. Its only task should be to initialize the object to a valid state. Processing input or generating output is not its responsibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for. To get each variable individually, would this be a good way of doing so?: http://pastie.org/pastes/10516156/text

Comment: I would include validation in the constructor to make sure that arrival time and hour stay are valid, and move the calculation of the pickup time to the getter: `public function get_pickupTime() { return date('H:i', (strtotime($this->arrivalTime) + $this->hourStay)); }`